# Angular async pipe usage difference

Tags: angular

For example, if I have an Observable in my component and I want to use it in my template in multiple places or I need to put the Observable value into the child component in case of only the result is not `null`

**my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
   myObservable$: Observable<SomeData | null>;
}
```

I can do it in these different ways:

**First way**

```
<child-component *ngIf="myObservable | async as data" [data]="data"></child-component>
```

**Second way**

```
<child-component *ngIf="myObservable | async" [data]="myObservable | async"></child-component>
```

I would to know is there any performance difference or usage recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `First way` is the preferred way because each `| async` pipe is a subscription.

In the `Second way` you are subscribing twice and you can have a performance hit (doubt you will notice it).

Imagine your observable stream was something like this:

```
myObservable$ = anotherObservable$.pipe(map(complicatedStuffHere()), map(moreComplicatedStuff()));
```

With the 2nd way, `complicatedStuffHere()` and `moreComplicatedStuffHere()` will be called twice. Basically, each `async` is a new subscription and it can cause a performance hit.

Comment: thank you AliF50 for your answer, but I think you are not right about the second way, it will be called only once and will notify both listeners

Comment: let me create a simple reproduction example so we can test what you said.

Comment: ah yes, you are right, it will be called twice, https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mncsxk?file=index.ts here is the reproduction example if you will need, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to show some block based on your observable value, the best way to do it is the following way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myObservable | async as data">
   <child-component [data]="data"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

In this case, you don't create an extra HTML-component and we get the value for our `child-component`.

Also, remember to avoid passing observables into the components. Components have to have values in their inputs.

Comment: Roman Thank you for your answer. yeah you are right, I will be careful